# A comparison between the adjectives "Brutal", "Savage" and "Merciless"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I am going to write a paragraph about an international disaster. But I have no idea which choice is proper / fixed / better sounding in this context:

> The previous Saturday the United Nations Human Rights Council strongly condemned X for its .......... attacks on civilians, in a resolution that was stronger in criticism than the one passed by the Security Council on the same day. By a majority vote the Council asked X to immediately stop its attacks.

a. [brutal](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/brutal) 
b. [savage](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/savage) 
c. [merciless](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/merciless)

According to the dictionary definitions:

**Brutal** = cruel, violent, and completely without feelings 
**Savage** = extremely violent, wild, or frightening 
**Merciless** = having or showing no mercy

As you see, these definitions are so close that a leaner like me can fall into doubt about how he/she should make a distinction between them and find a direct equivalent in their mother language(s).

That was why I decided to bring it up here to ask you for your opinions.

PS. I see no difference between "brutal" and "merciless", but "savage" has a slightly more violence / harshness involved in my mind, which I cannot explain. However, You are free to dispute it.

Comment: This board doesn't really give writing advice. However, _savage_ is more likely to be used of an attack by a lone criminal (a wild, perhaps deranged person) and _brutal_ of harsh treatment by an organisation.

Comment: KB's comment makes me ask: are you simply wanting the appropriate adjective, or should it add information? I feel like savage implies something more impulsive -- one minister made a snap decision and the police followed orders -- whereas brutal is when they had meetings and consensus.

Comment: Your example context sounds like a news article. Regardless of what adjective you choose, I would infer from it that the UNHRC used that adjective in its condemnation.

Comment: Off topic: there're 2 'Council's in your quoted paragraph, so the last sentence is ambiguous. (Which one asked?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Meanings

### [Brutal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brutal)

*Brutal* is the word most associated with violence here.

When old McDonald kills a cow he can:

1. Give it an overdose of sleeping drugs to gently kill it
2. Cut it up with a chainsaw, smash it t pieces with a slegehammer, etc

Method 2 is *brutal*. It involves a lot of (unnecessary and excessive) violence.

If you know Mortal Kombat, you probably now the "Finish him. Brutality" bit. In those scenes, it's brutal because the characters are killed cruelly and violently.

Of course, *brutal* doesn't always mean *violent* and *grim*. It can, in some cases, be replaced with less violent synonyms like *cruel, murderous, harsh, inhuman,* etc.

### [Savage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savage)

*Savage* is often associated with animalistic and uncivilized things.

It can be used to mean things like:

- not under human control
- wild
- rude
- uncultured

We sometimes say "savage beasts" to talk about wild animals untamed by humans.

### [Merciless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merciless)

You should understand what "mercy" is, since that's where "merciless" comes from.

[Mercy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mercy) can mean pity, lenience,  compassion, favor, etc. *Merciless* just means "without mercy".

Imagine you're a level 100 player playing against a level 1 player in a chess game. The difference in your levels is huge. If you show mercy, you go easy on them. If you're *merciless*, you beat them without mercy, as if the level difference isn't there.

## In your case...

### Brutal

X attacked civilians such that it became a bloodbath. Bodies everywhere, blood stains every corner. The scene has become grim and gory.

### Savage

X attacked civilians like animals. X's president doesn't care if those people were human. X's soldier killed everyone in sight, men, women and children. The pillage homes, acted like animals.

### Merciless

X had major military superiority over Y (the civilian side). The knew Y couldn't fight back, but attacked anyway. They didn't want to risk an attack from Y. It's like dropping a nuclear bomb on a city with no means to counter counter nuclear weapons.

## tl;dr

**Brutal** can mean violent and grim.

**Savage** can mean "like an animal".

**Merciless** can mean "without pity/compassion".

Comment: I got the point @John Zhau. Just out of curiosity, may I know what would be your own choice here?

Comment: That would depend on how you view X and how you want your readers to view X. An army killing everyone they see? **Bruta**l. Soldiers killing mindlessly like animals? **Savage**. X massively overpowers the civilian side? **Merciless**.

Comment: I would avoid 'savage' these days because of its association with the racist noun spelled the same used about indigenous peoples in colonial times.

Comment: Even without that association (which I didn't know about), it's probably not a good word to describe and army or its country. It can make you sound like "The people of country X are animals!", which doesn't sound good in academic papers and can lead to more friction.

Comment: With all due respect @John Zhau, I disagree! There are some occasions in which you never ever can substitute this word for another one. For instance may I know what you and Michael Harvey would use instead of this word to describe the genocide and senseless killings which were going on by Daish group in Iraq up to just several months ago?!

Comment: In some cases, yes, "savage" would fit better. You can say a murderer who kills for fun a savage. However, when you're writing an academic paper related to something like politics, openly calling people "savages" may not be the best choice. Imaging someone like Bill Nye saying "The American soldiers killed like savages". That may raise some conflict and put the speaker (you) in trouble. After all, "savage" is more often used to express things like "uncultured" or "rude". "Brutal" and "merciless" don't carry the same kind of insulting and sound less subjective.

Comment: In my mind the fitness of "savage" to describe an attack also depends on the level of technology used. I would be more inclined to call low-tech methods like machete-wielding soldiers "savage" than I would a high-tech attack like a drone strike.

Comment: @A-friend, calling the Islamic State "savage" gets you into exactly the trouble that Michael Harvey suggested.  There's a long and ignoble tradition (the colonialist tradition mentioned above) of referring to Muslims, Arabs, and any non-European people as "savages." For a full explanation, read Edward Said's [*Orientalism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientalism_(book)). The very short version is that using this language to talk about these groups 1) associates you with racists 2) is misinformed, relying on an assumption that these people would stop acting this way, if only they would...

Comment: ...hurry up and get civilized/Westernized/Chiristianized.  In reality cultural “development” is not linear, not uniform, and maybe not even real.  One might find similarities between ISIS’s killings and the US’s unrepentant murder (via drone strikes) of innocent civilians, or of American police officers’ proclivity for killing black people, but the American military and police are rarely called “savage”

Comment: @MichaelHarvey : then why not forbid using the word "avoid" as well, because it can be associated with avoiding problems one should address? Using your logic we can find a negative connotation for every word in the English language (find a brutal slave owner who use that word 200 years ago), and so we can ban every single word in the English language.

Comment: @Vsz - I think you need to come up with something better than that.

Comment: 'Brutal' and 'savage' are related to violence, but 'merciless' is not, per se. Also, 'merciless' implies _lack_ of mercy, that is, there should've been mercy (because it is usually expected or was explicitly requested, say).

Comment: @PabloH "Savage" doesn't necessarily meant "violent". It can mean things below or outside of societal standards. Simple eating noodles with your hands in a high-class restaurant can get you called *savage*.

Comment: @JohnZhau You have a point. But according to Oxford Dictionary's definitions (now [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/savage)), usage meaning 'uncivilized' is "dated, offensive". And if I were to delicately eat noodles as you say, I'd more on the weirdo rather than savage side, perhaps? [In the context of the question I recon 'savage' would typically elicit an image of violence.]

Comment: @PabloH "Savage" doesn't necessarily mean "uncivilized". It holds multiple meanings, and "uncivilized" is just one of them. Also, eating noodles delicately wouldn't exactly make you a weirdo. Rather, it'd probably make you seem more refined. If you eat noodles with your bare hands, you may be seen as weird, silly, etc. If you, however, eat noodles by shoving your face in the bowl like a dog would, you *may* be called "savage". The "dated" in your example synonym refers to things like eating like a caveman, which is now considered an uncivilized act.

Comment: Bonus: "savage" doesn't always have a negative notion. It can also be used positively to describe a good insult or come back. For example, **Charlie**: "Paul is ugly."; **Paul**: "That was uncalled for!"; **Charlie**: "Your face is uncalled for.". That is what we call a *savage* come back/insult, and we can call Charlie a *savage* for coming up with such a good insult. In spoken English, especially among close friends and circles, "savage" is often used on such good insults.